# Find UMVUE in a uniform distribution setting

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, uniform-distribution, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be independent and uniformly distributed on $(\theta_1-\theta_2,\theta_1+\theta_2)$ for $\theta_1 \in \mathbb{R}$, $\theta_2>0$.

Find UMVUEs for

a) $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$,

b) $\theta_1/\theta_2$.

Naturally, I would like to use the Lehmann-Scheffé theorem that says:

If $V$ is a complete, sufficient statistic for $\theta$ and $\mathbb{E}_\theta[g(V)]=h(\theta)$ holds. Then $g(V)$ is an UMVUE for $h(\theta)$.

So first, I have to find such a statistic for any of my $\theta$s.

In the lecture we learned that $(X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$ sufficient for $(a,b)$ if the $X_i$ are uniform on $(a,b)$ (where $X_{(1)}<...<X_{(n)}$ is the order statistic for $X_1, ..., X_n$).

So it follows that in my setting $(X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$ is sufficient for $(\theta_1-\theta_2,\theta_1+\theta_2)$? But looking at the proof, $(X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$ is already a sufficient statistic for $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$, too, right?

So I have to check for completeness and thus show that for all functions $g$ mapping from the range of $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{E}_\theta[g(X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})]=0$ for all $\theta=(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ follows $\mathbb{P}_\theta(g(X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})=1)=1$ $\mathbb{P}_\theta$-almost-surely.

Here I'm stuck: How can I show that?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can. At least if X is distributed on $(\theta,\theta + 1)$, then $(X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$ is sufficient, but not complete.

Lets say $g(X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$ is a function of your statistic. Then

$\mathbb{E}_{\theta}[X_{(n)} - X_{(1)}] = \mathbb{E}_{\theta}[X_{(n)}] - \mathbb{E}_{\theta}[ X_{(1)}] = (\theta + n/(n+1)) - (\theta + 1/(n+1)) = (n-1)/(n+1)$

Then $g$ defined as

$g(X_{(1)}, X_{(n)}) := X_{(n)} - X_{(1)} - (n-1)/(n+1)$

would be 0 $\forall \theta$ and thus not complete.

As I said, the setting is slightly different though. Let me know if you find a definite solution - I'm looking at the same problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I realize you don't yet have enough reputation, but this is better as a comment as opposed to an answer. Regards

Comment: Thanks :-) I've tried to elaborate a bit.

Comment: Looks excellent +1

Comment: The case $U(\theta,\theta+1)$ is a completely different problem and sheds no light on this particular exercise.

Answer (score 1):

That $T=(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ is sufficient for $\theta_1,\theta_2$ is verified easily using Factorisation theorem. And the proof of $T$ being a complete statistic is similar to the argument presented [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225580/jointly-complete-sufficient-statistics-uniforma-b).

Alternatively, if $g$ is any (measurable) function of $T$, then after some effort it *can* be shown by differentiating both sides of $E\,[g(T)]=0$ wrt $\theta_1,\theta_2$ that $g$ is identically zero with probability $1$ for all $\theta_1,\theta_2$.

Since $X_i\stackrel{\text{ i.i.d}}\sim U(\theta_1-\theta_2,\theta_1+\theta_2)$, we have $Y_i=(X_i-(\theta_1-\theta_2))/(2\theta_2)\stackrel{\text{ i.i.d}}\sim U(0,1)$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Now it is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution) that $Y_{(1)}\sim \text{Beta}(1,n)$ and $Y_{(n)}\sim \text{Beta}(n,1)$.

So,

\begin{align}
E\,[X_{(1)}]&=2\theta_2 E(Y_{(1)})+\theta_1-\theta_2
\\&=\frac{2\theta_2}{n+1}+\theta_1-\theta_2
\end{align}

And

\begin{align}
E\,[X_{(n)}]&=2\theta_2 E(Y_{(n)})+\theta_1-\theta_2
\\&=\frac{2n\theta_2}{n+1}+\theta_1-\theta_2
\end{align}

Solving for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ from the above equations we get

$$\theta_1=E\left[\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{2}\right]\qquad,\qquad \theta_2=E\left[\frac{n+1}{2(n-1)}\left(X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}\right)\right]$$

These unbiased estimators of $\theta_1,\theta_2$ are functions of $T$, hence they are the corresponding UMVUEs by Lehmann-Scheffe theorem.

---

We can guess that an unbiased estimator of $\theta_1/\theta_2$ based on $T$ is some function of $(X_{(1)}+X_{(n)})/(X_{(n)}-X_{(1)})$.

Now,

\begin{align}
E\left[\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}}\right]&=E\left[\frac{Y_{(n)}+Y_{(1)}}{Y_{(n)}-Y_{(1)}}\right]+\frac{\theta_1-\theta_2}{\theta_2}E\left[\frac{1}{Y_{(n)}-Y_{(1)}}\right]
\end{align}

Using the [joint density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_the_uniform_distribution) of $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)})$ the above expression is found to  be exactly equal to $\frac{n}{n-2}\left(\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}\right)$, suggesting that the UMVUE of $\theta_1/\theta_2$ is $$\frac{n-2}{n}\left(\frac{X_{(n)}+X_{(1)}}{X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}}\right)$$